# Is there a class / method to handle dragging views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, draggable, uitouch

I found a [useful tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/) to get started in understanding how to Cocoa handles touch events.  I've used this as a base to create a custom script, I'm trying to make a UIView draggable, very similar to the native Maps application.

- I've written a custom script, using
  the touchesBegan method it will
  capture where the input began and
  compare it to the centre point of the
  UIView using some conditional
  statements.
- The touchesMoved method will do some
  further conditional statements to
  determine whether the touch start
  point and the center of the view will
  move positively or negative.
- I've also captured the views
  boundaries so it doesn't go too far
  out.

it's lacking the polished finished found in other applications such as Maps, or scrolling a UITable, such as the ease effect after the user has released their fingers, and the snapping effect when it reaches the boundaries is horrible.

Is there a method that takes a view and makes it draggable like this?  If not I'll continue to refine my script.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for UIScrollView